# How to retrieve news to my cordova mobile app

Tags: jquery, html, json, cordova, mobile

I've been searching the web for an API where I can retrieve news (gaming news more specifically) for my cordova Project. So far I did not find any API that provides gaming news. What i could figure out that i need to implement an RSS feature on my app so that I can retrieve news from it, but still didn't find "free" RSS API that I can you. Any suggestions?

I'm coding with HTML, JS, Jquery, Jquery mobile, JSON, XML

Comment: I didnt find anything useful so i made my own news system, where a "reporter" writes and uploads a news and shows automatically to the user

Answer (score 0):

1. You may search mash-up / api directories, such as [programmable web](http://www.programmableweb.com/)
2. You may make a search in "rss search engines". Such as: [[1]](http://ctrlq.org/rss/)
3. You may search for bigger game distributers'/publishers' blogs. Such as steam, playstation... Both have rss apis.
4. You may search game magazines those have rss feeds.

After all, you will find lots of rss feeds.